# In ADO.Net Data Services how do I check if an entity is already in the context?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have an ADO.Net Data Service that I am using to do a data import.  There are a number of entities that are linked to by most entities.  To do that during import I create those entities first, save them and then use .SetLink(EntityImport, "NavigationProperty", CreatedEntity).  Now the first issue that I ran into was that the context did not always know about CreatedEntity (this is due to each of the entities being imported independently and a creation of a context as each item is created - I'd like to retain this functionality - i.e. I'm trying to avoid "just use one context" as the answer).

So I have a .AddToCreatedEntityType(CreatedEntity) before attempting to call SetLink.  This of course works for the first time, but on the second pass I get the error message "the context is already tracking the entity".

Is there a way to check if the context is already tracking the entity (context.Contains(CreatedEntity) isn't yet implemented)?  I was thinking about attempting a try catch and just avoiding the error, but that seems to create a new CreatedEntity each pass.  It is looking like I need to use a LINQ to Data Services to get that CreatedEntity each time, but that seems innefficient - any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look at the [EntityState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx) property of your entity.

Only if it is of the value EntityState.Detached than you have to add it to your context.

Do not forget the following remark:

> This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute
>   attribute that allows a bitwise
>   combination of its member values.

I would create a extension method:

```
public static class EntityObjectExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsTracked(this EntityObject self)
    {
        return (self.EntityState & EntityState.Detached) != EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to check whether the context was tracking the entity that I wanted to update (or add) I was pretty disapointed when I found that the context.Entites.Contains(currentItem) didn't work.

I got around it using:

```
if (context.Entities.Where(entities => entities.Entity == currentItem).Any())
{
   this.service.UpdateObject(currentItem);                    
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't have, what to do. It means what is the else part?